# Use iPhone 5 for Retina 3,5" debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, retina-display

I recently gave my iPhone 4 to a friend so I don't have a Retina 3,5" Device anymore. 
I wondered if theres a way without much tweaking the app code to get the 3,5" Version on the iPhone 5(like an App which isn't optimized).

Comment: Or you could use iPhone simulator, which is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not include (or temporarily remove) `Default-568h@2x.png` if will run as a 3,5" app.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to test on the iPhone simulator and change the hardware from retina 4 inch to retina 3.5 inch!

Or ask your friend to borrow their phone and test it on the device which involves certificates so it's slightly more inconvenient.

Either way, it's not too hard to test on multiple devices. Additionally, if you have an iPod touch that is older than the 5th generation, that works too.

Generally you can purchase, cheaply, used iPod touches online to use for development testing. Good luck!